# Getting values from jQuery object array based on key not array number

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, .post

I need to get values from an object returned via $.post but the order of the 2 arrays can change, so I need to get them based on the key. The problem is that the key is returned inside the array. Example below.

```
{
Id: "AETVXXXXXXXX", HasError: false, Error: null, FinanceQuotations: Array(2)}
    Error: null
    FinanceQuotations: Array(2)
        0:
            Blocks: [{…}]
            Error: null
            Finance: {Key: "HP", Notifications: Array(0), Quote: {…}, Product: {…}, Retailer: {…}}
            HasError: false
            __proto__: Object
        1:
            Blocks: [{…}]
            Error: null
            Finance: {Key: "PCP", Notifications: Array(0), Quote: {…}, Product: {…}, Retailer: {…}}
            HasError: false
            __proto__: Object
            length: 2
            __proto__: Array(0)
        HasError: false
        Id: "AETVXXXXXXXX"
        __proto__: Object
}
```

I would normally drill down into the array and assign the value to the var using something like the below:

```
var durationValue = (value.FinanceQuotations[1].Blocks[0].Details[0].DisplayValue);
```

But because the array order is now liable to change, it won't always return the same product first in the array return the wrong values.

How can I loop over the arrays and get the values for the key? The two keys, in this case, are "HP" and "PCP"...

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You would have to perform a `find()` first, matching on the finance key equal to HP or PCP, before drilling down into their related blocks

Comment: None of this would be jQuery.  jQuery is for DOM manipulation and lookups.  This is object traversing.  It's going to be just vanilla javascript.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score -1):

The only way is creating "associative array"-object like this:

```
var a = {
  "HP": ...
  "PCP": ...
  "OTHER_KEY": ...
}
```

and then iterate items using "for-in"-cycles:

```
for (key in a) {
   alert(key);
   alert(a[key]);
}
```

Comment: A programmer should always have extreme doubt when someone says "the only way".

Comment: the other ways may be for non-programmers ;)